# Does the term memory in sagemaker mean GPU memory or CPU memory?

Tags: memory, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0, amazon-sagemaker

I have been training models on Sagemaker using the tensorflow estimator, and seen the failure message below quite often. In the beginning, I assumed it to be GPU memory, but it occurs to me today that it might be CPU memory. Does anyone know the answer?

[failure message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NspN2.png)

[metric curves from a failed job](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6nol.png)

I have been googling for an answer and realized if it's a GPU memory issue, the error message (in logs) will probably look like the screenshot below

[example GPU oom error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/grZyI.png)

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the instance type you are using, you can check the list of instances for training here: https://aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/pricing/. There will be both CPU and GPU Util metrics for GPU based instances that you can analyze in CloudWatch metrics.

To deal with your specific error we need some more detail, what's the size of your training dataset and what is your data source? You can utilize S3, or FsX Lustre which is generally better for when we are dealing with TBs of data. If you are utilizing S3 it is also important to set data distribution to shardedbyS3Key so that you are not copying your dataset into each instance behind the training job.